# MySqlConnector Doesnt have ExecuteScalar, ExecuteNonQuery, ExecuteDataset

Tags: c#, ado.net, mysql-connector

We are trying to move from MySql.Data to MySqlConnector package.
After installing the package MySqlConnector [Link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/) getting this error : 'MySqlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'ExecuteNonQuery'.

Looks like MySqlConnector doesn't have predefined methods ExecuteScalar, ExecuteNonQuery, ExecuteDataset.

Is there any workaround or any way we can write wrappers for this methods.

```
public int ExecuteNonQuery()
{
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    connection.Open();
    try
    {
        return MySqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(connection, CommandTextForMySqlHelper, ParameterArrayForMySqlHelper);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
        connection.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're better off rewriting your code. Start with the method you posted: `throw ex;` is an abomination, and the better option, `throw;`, is pointless (you might as well not catch the exception at all). Using `try`/`finally` instead of `using` is a poor choice, too. The methods of `MySqlHelper` are naively (read: poorly) implemented and really shouldn't be used. "Easier" is not better there. I imagine MySqlConnector doesn't have them for that reason. Switching to MySqlConnector is a good thing, but you've tied yourself to MySql.Data's cruft and you need to break that link.

Comment: To summarize parts the previous comment: the current posted method is 18 lines. You can make it BETTER by reducing it down to 6 lines (no try/catch, using instead of finally/close/dispose)

Answer (score 1):

MySqlHelper is not part of the MySqlConnector package. Create the method yourself:

```
public static DataSet ExecuteDataset(
    MySqlConnection connection,
    string commandText,
    params MySqlParameter[]? commandParameters)
{
    using MySqlCommand selectCommand = new MySqlCommand();
    selectCommand.Connection = connection;
    selectCommand.CommandText = commandText;
    selectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    if (commandParameters != null)
    {
        foreach (MySqlParameter commandParameter in commandParameters)
            selectCommand.Parameters.Add(commandParameter);
    }
    using MySqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(selectCommand);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(ds);
    selectCommand.Parameters.Clear();
    return ds;
}
```

Use:

```
using var connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
DataSet dataSet = ExecuteDataset(connection, CommandTextForMySqlHelper, ParameterArrayForMySqlHelper);
// no need to open or close the connection, it's opened and closed in Fill
// but even without it would be closed because of the using-statement
```

Comment: If you're going to create it yourself, though, improve it by properly disposing of disposable objects created within the method.

Answer (score 1):

Does not answer the question (so just community wiki), but just to rewrite the original using better practice:

```
public DataSet ExecuteDataSet()
{
    using var cn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    return MySqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(cn, CommandTextForMySqlHelper, ParameterArrayForMySqlHelper);
}
```

18 lines down to 5 (or 15 down to 2, depending on how you count) without any loss of function, and the code is objectively better.

Otherwise, the ExecuteScalar(), ExecuteNonQuery(), and ExecuteReader() methods are part of the Command object, and you Fill() a DataSet as part of a DataAdapter